# Hide tableview based on picker view section

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I want to show hide tableview based on picker view selection.In picker view i have an array of four values. If i select value(2) tableview can hide or else it will hide.

Below is picker view code :

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    textfie.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrMsg objectAtIndex:row]];


    NSLog([arrmsg1 objectAtIndex:row]);
    NSLog(@"%@",json);

}
```

[image: screenshot for picker view below tableview]

Comment: Share any screenshot of your requirement?

Comment: You want to show diff data on selection of picker view row right?

Comment: try with `Hidden Property` of `UITableView` like 'tableView.hidden = YES`

Comment: if i put in picker view as tableview.hidden=yes means its showing error. when i select pickerview 4th row tableview can hide

Comment: is that a tableview controller?

Comment: i hardcore tableview in viewcontroller @Sherin

Comment: check my answer.hope it help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like,

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    textfie.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrMsg objectAtIndex:row]];

    if (row == 1) {

        self.myTableview.hidden = YES;
    }


    NSLog([arrmsg1 objectAtIndex:row]);
    NSLog(@"%@",json);

 }
```

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using tableview alpha to zero.

Check below code

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    if (row == 3) {
        self.yourableView.alpha = 0.0;
    }
    else{
        self.yourTableView.alpha = 1.0;

    }
}];

}
```